# Very fast short-circuit detection

Tags: mosfet, current, protection, short-circuit, shunt

I am working on a high-current MOSFET switch project. I would like to implement short-circuit/overcurrent protection, that would be fast enough to prevent MOSFETs from blowing up.

In the actual application, I am using a HAL sensor to measure current, but it won't allow me to take any action quickly because of its delay.

How should I realize this protection? Should I do it by using a shunt and a high-quality op-amp, or is there a better solution?

Comment: Details of the MOSFET switch schematic are needed.

Comment: In terms of speed, shunt resistor will be hard to beat.

Comment: How much is "high current"? How fast is "very fast"?

Comment: MOSFET switch is composed of 5 MOSFETs in parallel, with 22 Ohm gate resistance each and 1.5A driver. 

It has to handle 150A continuous current, has been tested on the bench. I don't know how long does it take to blow up MOSFETs while short circuit of battery (passing like 1-2kA), maybe I should ask question about what solution is the fastest one.

Comment: A comparator will be faster than an "equivalent" opamp because of its lack of compensation.

Comment: A possibility would be placing a inductor in series that limits the speed at which current can ramp up, buying time for a overcurrent circuit to act.

Comment: @Unimportant yep, but don't forget that then disrupting the high current quickly will come with sparks

Comment: will the classic current limiting topologies work, using V_DS as the sense voltage?  There also exist current sensing mosfets, which mirror a small fraction of the output to a side circuit, which might make your life quite easy actually. Though they may not be available in the size needed.

Comment: It is important to mention the type of load.  If it is AC/DC, inductive, resistive.
(Interrupting the high current will come with sparks if there is no flyback).

Comment: I was wondering about inductor, but I think that it will provide too much wastes while normal operation.

About sparks - I am going to apply transil diodes where I can, especially in the MOSFET circuit in order to prevent any failure during disconnecting while full load.

@Pete

Comment: @PeteW I was wondering about that solution, there are even gate drivers that supports it.

Answer (score 1):

Use Vds detection with minimal dead time; drivers with short circuit protection use that methods.
EG for high voltage
https://gate-driver.power.com/products/scale-idriver-ic-family/sid11x2k/

If you have inductive loads or long cabling, detecting the current with a shunt is too slow
and when you trigger the shutdown the current could take to much time to reverse.
Specially with 5 Mosfet in parallel you can have problem to handle the energy in the circuit.

Comment: can you explain to me why detecting over-current with a shunt would be slow, for an inductive load?

Answer (score 1):

One cheap option is an in-PCB current transformer: run the output trace in an inner layer of the PCB, and use vias and perpendicular traces on top and bottom layers to form a solenoid around it. Load the secondary winding with a resistor, and use a fast comparator to detect overcurrent.

Given the currents involved, the output trace can end up as two parallel fairly wide traces on layers 2 and 3, with the current transformer wrapped around them on layers 1, 4 and the vias.

Of course this will only detect transient short circuits, not a slow increase in current - but should be enough for such a purpose.

VDS measurement with deadtime would be a more typical option.